# React Native Firebase Analytics window.document.getElementsByTagName Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I want to connect firebase analytics to my react native project, but when I write this code in my app,

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app'
import {getAnalytics} from 'firebase/analytics';
```

const firebaseConfig = {

.
.
.

};

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

i am facing this error in my terminal

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is
> not an object (evaluating 'window.document.getElementsByTagName')

Comment: Did you decide on this question? I'm also faced with it, but still searching for a decision.

Comment: Are you using the Firebase JavaScript SDK with React Native iOS? I'm also experiencing this same issue and wondering if the problem is that the JS SDK is incompatible with iOS for analytics...?